# How to get/identity the Azure DevOps Server base URL from the extension?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I’m developing an extension for both Azure DevOps Services and Server but I’m struggling to get the base URL for the Azure DevOps Server version once I have some navigations to the target resource, such as: Pull Request details.

Is there any way to get it? For instance:

Azure DevOps Services

- dev.azure.com/organization
- organization.visualstudio.com

Azure DevOps Server

- serverName/{?}
- serverName:8080/{tfs}/{?}

Comment: Which tfs version does your extension target? In [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/work-with-urls?view=azure-devops&tabs=csharpgeneric#how-to-get-an-organizations-url) there exists some ways that requires the organization name or ID(devops service) to get the base url. You can check it to get some help.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT that page only seems to describe how to get various api urls if you *already know* the base url. What's requested is how to get the server url (e.g. protocol, port, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code:

1. Use `document.referrer` from the plugin as a URL source.
2. Locate the project name and extract the part of the URL before the project name.

   ```
   const url = document.referrer;
   // how to detect base Url: get projectName and find 'ProjectName/_'
   // http://tfs2017-test:8080/tfs/Org/MyProject/_apps/hub/...
   const projectService = await SDK.getService<IProjectPageService>(CommonServiceIds.ProjectPageService);
   const project = await projectService.getProject();

   if (!project) {
       throw new Error("Cannot get project.")
   }

   const findStr = `${project.name}/_`;
   const index = url.indexOf(findStr);

   if (index < 0) {
       throw new Error(`URL '${url}' does not contain '${findStr}' substring`);
   }

   // extract from url without '_'
   this._baseUrl = url.substring(0, index + findStr.length - 1);
   ```

Edit 04.05.2021:
Because document.referrer is not working good for some browsers, I am using now more "DevOps way":

```
// https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sdk/issues/28
this._locationService = await SDK.getService<ILocationService>(CommonServiceIds.LocationService);
const hostBaseUrl = await this._locationService.getResourceAreaLocation(
    CoreRestClient.RESOURCE_AREA_ID
);

console.log(`hostBaseUrl: ${hostBaseUrl}`);

const projectService = await SDK.getService<IProjectPageService>(CommonServiceIds.ProjectPageService);
const project = await projectService.getProject();

if (!project) {
    throw new Error("Cannot get project.")
}

this._baseUrl = `${hostBaseUrl}${project.name}/`;
console.log(`baseUrl: ${this._baseUrl}`);
```